# How to use TagHelpers in asp.net core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm trying to make a custom tag helper work in asp-net core 3.0.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace MyProject.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("p", Attributes = "markdown")]
    [HtmlTargetElement("markdown")]
    [OutputElementHint("p")]
    public class MarkdownTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public async override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent("<p>lkajsdlkjasdlkjasd</p>");
        }
    }
}
```

`_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@using MyProject
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, MyProject
```

I'm trying to reference `<markdown></markdown>` in the `TermsConditions.cshtml` file. (Full file:)

```
<div>
    <markdown></markdown>
</div>
```

[image]

But still, the `markdown` tag is never replaced when calling that view.

I found many questions, blogs, ..., but nothing worked so far. I checked for the following common mistakes.

- Tag helper class is made public
- _ViewImports.cshtml is placed in Views folder where all the other views reside
- Tried the async and non-async version of `Process`

#### Question:

What do I have to do in order to make TagHelpers work?

Comment: It looks like you're doing everything right, assuming that the assembly with the tag helper is called FeatureNinjas?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, yes, just updated the post to be correct. `MyProject` is the namespace. `Mp.Web` is the assembly name.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, based on your comment, I also added `@addTagHelper *, Mp.Web` to `_ViewImports.cshtml`, and now it works. So you really have to use the **assembly name** here, not the namespace. It is written in the docs, but I somehow missed this. Thanks! (Just post this as an answer and I will accept it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks right, from the available information. So I suspect that this isn't actually your assembly name;

```cs
@addTagHelper *, MyProject
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'll save someone time.. In my case the `AssemblyName` was missing in the current project, so the tag helpers was not applied.

In `_ViewImports.cshtml` file should be used this `AssemblyName` like:

```
@using AssemblyName
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, AssemblyName
```

And don't forget to add these assemblies:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you are applying it correctly..

Change

```
[HtmlTargetElement("p", Attributes = "markdown")]
[HtmlTargetElement("markdown")]
[OutputElementHint("p")]
```

To

```
[HtmlTargetElement("markdown")]
```

In your original code, you would need to do something like `<p markdown="some text"></p>`